# Bounty based on solving problem in code located in a GitHub link

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bounty

A poster asked a question here: [Returning SwingWorker result back to EDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709587/returning-swingworker-result-back-to-edt) that [I then answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59709599/522444) based on the code posted in his question. He commented to my answer that my solution did not help him based on his real code, code that he posted in GitHub. I commented back that all code should be present in the main question, not in a link, preferably as a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). He never replied but then proceded to edit his question, linking to his GitHub code-base, and placing a bounty on the question.

I thought about editing his question, removing the link, but then I thought not to do this since I'd be using my editing privileges in a situation that involves me directly, and so I'm at a loss of what to do -- suggestions please?

Comment: I'm not a java expert, but is the relevant code not contained in the question itself? The link seems to be only a supplement for the given code?

Comment: @BDL: not according to the OP. I solved the issue in the code that was posted in the question, but the OP states that my solution doesn't work as per his linked-to code (which I have not opened, to be honest as a matter of principle)

Comment: If the OP's example code isn't representative of their real code, then it isn't an MRE; that much is simple in my opinion. I don't think removing the link is a good idea, but the OP *should* be updating their question with representative code in their question. Questions should not **require** that you use an off-site resource like Github to get the full information (there are some exceptions though, such as PasteBin for large logs that may be required or Paste the Plan for SQL Execution plans).

Comment: @Larnu: my feelings *exactly*

Comment: I'd be minded to flag it for a moderator to have the bounty removed so it can be closed. If the question isn't answerable without reference to code that's off-site (which is therefore potentially transient) then Close > Off-Topic > It's seeking debugging help but needs more information feels appropriate. I would VTC for exactly that if not for the bounty being present (and the only reason I haven't flagged, yet, is the presence of this meta question)

Comment: Going to ask folks not to downvote the OP's question before seeing how they respond to this issue

Comment: The OP did amend their qusetion 10 hours ago, and make a lot of code changes, @HovercraftFullOfEels . The github link is still there though. Did that edit not address the concerns in your question (sorry I can't read Java, so I've personally no idea).

Comment: The OP has not yet provided an MRE which will likely be necessary to answer the question to their satisfaction

Comment: Hi everyone, what can I do to get this question re-opened? I've made several edits and believe the question is now in compliance with SO standards. **Please** let me know if there's anything more I can do.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup: thank you for your update. The question is now an [mre], and I will try to update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been edited by the OP and is now an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and is answerable. It has been re-opened.